# OpenSCAP Tailoring - Possible to change rule severity

Tags: audit

Is it possible to change the severity of a rule using an OpenSCAP tailoring/customization file?

UPDATE (2022-04-13):

`refine-rule` seems like it could solve this but cannot find any documentation for whether you can use this in the customisation file.

Answer (score 1):

Profiles are defined in the repository : [ComplianceAsCode/content](https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content)

You can copy the desired configuration file to new file (or download the latest release from [GitHub](https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content/releases)) and then edit the severity of the rules according to your needs.

The example bellow edit the severity if the `auditd` service is disabled on macOS:

- On the file `ssg-macos10-15-ds.xml` find the line bellow:

`<xccdf-1.2:Rule id="xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_service_com_apple_auditd_enabled" selected="false" role="full" severity="high">`

- Change the severity from `high` to `low`

`<xccdf-1.2:Rule id="xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_service_com_apple_auditd_enabled" selected="false" role="full" severity="low">`

Note that the [severity](https://github.com/OpenSCAP/openscap/blob/596933b478a3800d51689688a0ee0c7b12c4d3d8/schemas/xccdf/1.1/xccdf-schema.xsd#L1822) value can be `unknown`, `info`, `low`, `medium` or `high`

- Save and use the modified profile:

```
 oscap xccdf eval --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_benchmark_macOS-1015 --results-arf results.xml --report report.html /path/to/new/edited/ssg-macos10-15-ds.xml
```

Where:
`xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_benchmark_macOS-1015` is the `id` of the benchmark as defined on the profile : `<xccdf-1.2:Benchmark id="xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_benchmark_macOS-1015" resolved="1" xml:lang="en-US" style="SCAP_1.2">`

**Updates**

Indeed, `refine-rule` can be used to change the `weight`, `severity` and `role` of a rule.

After saving the "Customization only", you can edit the rules in the XML file by adding for each rule the `refine-rule` according to your need :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xccdf:Tailoring xmlns:xccdf="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2" id="xccdf_scap-workbench_tailoring_default">
  <xccdf:benchmark href="/tmp/scap-workbench-HdQHny/ssg-rl8-ds.xml"/>
  <xccdf:version time="2022-04-16T15:02:00">1</xccdf:version>
  <xccdf:Profile id="xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_cui_customized" extends="xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_cui">
    <xccdf:title xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" override="true">Unclassified Information in Non-federal Information Systems and Organizations (NIST 800-171) [CUST$
    <xccdf:description xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" override="true">From NIST 800-171, Section 2.2:
Security requirements for protecting the confidentiality of CUI in nonfederal
information systems and organizations have a well-defined structure that
consists of:

(i) a basic security requirements section;
(ii) a derived security requirements section.

... 

"</xccdf:description>
    <xccdf:select idref="xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_audit_rules_file_deletion_events_rename" selected="true"/>
    <xccdf:select idref="xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_audit_rules_file_deletion_events" selected="true"/>
    <xccdf:refine-rule idref="xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_audit_rules_file_deletion_events_rename" weight="0" severity="low"/>
    <xccdf:refine-rule idref="xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_rule_audit_rules_file_deletion_events" weight="0" severity="low"/>
  </xccdf:Profile>
</xccdf:Tailoring>
```

**Result**

- Without customization
  [image: Without customization]
- With customization
  [image: With customization file]

More information can be found in [Specification for the
Extensible Configuration Checklist Description Format (XCCDF) Version 1.2](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Publications/nistir/7275/rev-4/final/documents/nistir-7275r4_updated-march-2012_markup.pdf) in section [6.5.3](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Publications/nistir/7275/rev-4/final/documents/nistir-7275r4_updated-march-2012_markup.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A120%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C69%2C720%2C0%5D)

#### Debug

**Testing the profile**

```
 oscap info --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_cui_customized ./ssg-rl8-ds-tailoring.xml
Document type: XCCDF Tailoring
Imported: 2022-04-18T06:04:53
Benchmark Hint: /tmp/scap-workbench-FGmUva/ssg-rl8-ds.xml
Profiles:
    Title: Unclassified Information in Non-federal Information Systems and Organizations (NIST 800-171) [CUSTOMIZED]
        Id: xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_cui_customized
```

Where `xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_cui_customized`is the `Profile-id` on the tailoring file `ssg-rl8-ds-tailoring.xml`.

**Generating guide**

```
oscap xccdf generate guide --verbose INFO --fetch-remote-resources --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_cui_customized  --output guide-profile_cui_customized.html --tailoring-file ./ssg-rl8-ds-tailoring.xml ./ssg-rl8-ds-tailoring.xml
```

On the generated guide, you can verify if the rule is as expected and that also can be used as reference for your custom tailoring profile.
[image: Generated profile guide]

Comment: I was hoping to use the tailoring/customization file for this though for tracability so we are always based off a known policy and the changes we apply are explicit and overlayed.

Comment: @REA_ANDREW I updated the answer with more details. Hope that can help!